# git-svn doesn't work with certificates

Tags: git, certificate, git-svn

I have access to SVN repository. Access is through HTTPS, I'm using certificate which was imported on my Windows machine and right now I'd like to use git-svn to clone that repository, do my work and push changes to that SVN, but I just get perl error:

```
Client certificate filename: Use of uninitialized value in chomp
```

Is there any way to show git where are my certificates? I think the main cause is that certificate and git just can't authenticate to that SVN, but maybe I'm wrong and it's something completely different. Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just solved this problem be editing the subversion global configuration in `~/.subversion/servers`. I added these lines to the bottom of that file in the `[global]` section:

```
ssl-client-cert-file = /home/myusername/certificate.pfx
store-passwords = yes
store-plaintext-passwords = yes
store-ssl-client-cert-pp = yes
store-ssl-client-cert-pp-plaintext = yes
```

When I then did a `git svn clone -s` it prompted me once for the password for the certificate, and then proceeded with the checkout. When I tried this originally, it was prompting me repeatedly for the certificate filename, because it was not being stored with the default servers file. Because it was not stored, it had to ask me for the certificate for every https request I guess. If I did a `^d` or `^c` to escape out of that loop then I would get the error about "uninitialized value in chomp".